# FFmpeg: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'mpegts'

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command on several video streams to pipe them into my TVHeadend server.

```
pipe:///usr/bin/ffmpeg -i *URL* -c copy -metadata service_provider="My Provider" -metadata service_name="My Service"-f mpegts pipe:1
```

This command works fine for most of the streams, but a few are throwing this error...

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9.3.0 (Alpine 9.3.0)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avresample --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --enable-libssh --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopus --enable-libaom --disable-debug
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[hls @ 0x7f7c03b0c5c0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x7f7c03b0c5c0] Opening '****' for reading
[hls @ 0x7f7c03b0c5c0] Opening '****' for reading
Input #0, hls, from '****:
Duration: N/A, start: 3116.333433, bitrate: N/A
Program 0 
Metadata:
variant_bitrate : 0
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Metadata:
variant_bitrate : 0
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
Metadata:
variant_bitrate : 0
[NULL @ 0x55f1a0fcec80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'mpegts'
mpegts: Invalid argument
```

The problem streams do work.
I searched before asking this question and everything I found was related to conversion.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?
The reason behind the using FFmpeg and piping is to eliminate issues with stream freezes. FFmpeg just handles hitches etc better than simply adding the URL straight into my TVHeadend server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from

```
-metadata service_name="My Service"-f mpegts pipe:1
```

to

```
-metadata service_name="My Service" -f mpegts pipe:1
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Thanks!

Comment: Can you believe someone else made the same mistake as well...